# How to anchor access accordion item

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, accordion

I know very little about javascript so this is really hard for me :(

I'm using [Tympanus](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FlexibleSlideToTopAccordion/index2.html) accordion but can't figure out how to link to an item and display it opened (using a anchor link e.g. page/#3442)

This accordion is very simple and easy to use but there is no further examples or maybe this is just impossible?!

I added IDs in links so I wish I could access `http://site.com/page#123` and see the opened item, there is an option to set the default opened item, `open = "the index"` I think I need a function to grab the ID from submitted URL and pass it dinamically to the accordion paramters but can't figure out how :( :

```
$.Accordion.defaults        = {

    open            : -1, //index of opened item, -1 is none, 0 is the 1st item etc
    oneOpenedItem           : false,
    speed           : 600,
    easing          : 'easeInOutExpo',
    scrollSpeed     : 900,
    scrollEasing            : 'easeInOutExpo'
};
```

Thanks for any help.

**Set in Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uwn4P/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this way:

```
        $(function() {
            if(window.location.hash) {
                var hash = window.location.hash;
                var newHashName = hash.replace("#","");
            } else {
                newHashName=-1;
            }

    $('#st-accordion').accordion({
    oneOpenedItem   : true,
            open: newHashName,
            });
        });
```

But note that the 1st tab is always `0`, the script uses index (starts from 0), so if you want to use specific IDs such names or post IDs, you have to modify the script itself (what I don't really know by now).

This means that if you have posts, you have to add a counting starting from `0` on your `<li>` elements and linking should be `site.com/page/` (the 1st tab), `site.com/page/#1` (the 2nd tab) etc

Answer (score 1):

window.location.hash will get you the hash from the address bar if that's what you are looking for.

So you can easily store it in a variable let's say like this:

```
var item;
if(window.location.hash) {
    item = window.location.hash;
} else {
    item=-1;
}
```

then simply pass the item to accordion in your call:

```
open            : item
```

I think this is simple enought but I'm not sure if this is actually what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for try tomca32, I have the following in accordion page :`<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {

    $('#st-accordion').accordion({
     oneOpenedItem : true
    });
            });
</script>` where window.location.hash should go?!

Comment: try just adding it to the accordion parameters like this: $('#st-accordion').accordion({ oneOpenedItem : true, open: item });

Comment: Tried and the accordion stop working, there's a error: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

Comment: I found that the classes exchange happens in the <li>, then added the ID e.g.:http://jsfiddle.net/Pv48B/